# Attempting to install package, missing kernel header

Tags: ubuntu, kernel, linux-headers

Currently running on the following system (output of cat /etc/os-release):

```
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS"
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION_ID="22.04"
VERSION="22.04.2 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish)"
VERSION_CODENAME=jammy
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
UBUNTU_CODENAME=jammy
```

vs output of uname -r which is 5.19.0-35-generic. I was not sure if this was actually an issue until I started trying to install git@github.com:dbeniamine/clevo-indicator.git to get better control of my fan speeds. At which point, after getting past the first part of installation I needed to run the following, which gave the following output.

```
sudo ./build_module.sh
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
linux-headers-5.19.0-35-generic is already the newest version (5.19.0-35.36~22.04.1).
linux-source is already the newest version (5.15.0.69.67).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
tar (child): linux-source-5.19.tar.xz: Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar (child): Error is not recoverable: exiting now
tar: Child returned status 2
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
./build_module.sh: line 38: cd: linux-source-5.19: No such file or directory
make: *** No rule to make target 'oldconfig'.  Stop.
make: *** No rule to make target 'scripts'.  Stop.
./build_module.sh: line 41: cd: drivers/acpi: No such file or directory
make: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.19.0-35-generic'
warning: the compiler differs from the one used to build the kernel
  The kernel was built by: x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc (Ubuntu 11.3.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 11.3.0
  You are using:           gcc (Ubuntu 11.3.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 11.3.0
scripts/Makefile.build:43: /usr/src/Makefile: No such file or directory
make[1]: *** No rule to make target '/usr/src/Makefile'.  Stop.
make: *** [Makefile:1850: /usr/src] Error 2
make: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.19.0-35-generic'
insmod: ERROR: could not load module ec_sys.ko: No such file or directory
Failed to insert the module, something might have failed during build
```

I am now unsure why this is missing or how I can get it to be added back / what needs to be installed to fix this.I should note the original reason for all of this was just to correctly detect my the fans in my machine following: https://www.reddit.com/r/System76/comments/lzz5i1/fan_speed_control_on_serval_ws/. This was because I was getting constant overheating, which I assumed was due to something being incorrectly installed. If anyone has an idea of how to address this that would be great!